# converting cascaded distionary in to list of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a data type, which is dictionary of a dictionary called 'count'

'Count' looks like this:

```
{
  'i0': 
     {0: 3756, 
      20000: 3860, 
      5000: 3794, 
      10000: 3811, 
      25000: 928, 
      15000: 3851
   }, 
  'i1': 
    {0: 3807, 
     20000: 3908, 
     5000: 3794, 
     10000: 3866, 
     25000: 728, 
     15000: 3897
    }, 
  'i2': 
    {0: 3756, 
     20000: 3865, 
     5000: 3822, 
     10000: 3791,
    } 
  }
```

So you can see that 'count' is a hash of 'units': i0, i1, i2...
and each 'unit' is a hash that has a key of 'time' and value as 'txn_count'

I need to create a two list.

list 1. This will be the cycle range [0, 5000, 10000,...25000]. Problem is this list needs to be inclusive of all the time for all the units. As you can see 'i2' only has 0, 5000, 10000 and 20000. But I need a list that has all the possible times in them for all the units: i0, i1, i2

list 2. This will be list of list showing counts per units i0, i1, i2. So in this case

```
[[3756, 3794, 3811, 3851, 3860, 928]
 [3807, 3794, 3866, 3897, 3908, 728]
 [3756, 3822, 3791,    0, 3865,   0]]
```

As you can see the index for outer list is units: i0, i1, i2
and index for inner list is txn_count values corresponding to the clock: 0, 5000, 10,000, 15,000, 20,000, 25,000.

How do I do this in python, especially with the challege of missing clocks and unsorted dictionary.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first to get the possible values you need*:

```
In [15]: possible = sorted({v for val in count.values() for v in val})

In [16]: possible
Out[16]: [0, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000]
```

Use `.get` dictionary method with default value of `0`:

```
In [17]: [[v.get(i, 0) for i in possible] for _, v in count.items()]
Out[17]:
[[3756, 3794, 3811, 3851, 3860, 928],
 [3756, 3822, 3791, 0, 3865, 0],
 [3807, 3794, 3866, 3897, 3908, 728]]
```

Now, if you need this to be in order by the keys, since dictionaries are unordered, you can sort the keys!

```
In [20]: keys = sorted(count)

In [21]: keys
Out[21]: ['i0', 'i1', 'i2']

In [22]: [[count[k].get(i, 0) for i in possible] for k in keys]
Out[22]:
[[3756, 3794, 3811, 3851, 3860, 928],
 [3807, 3794, 3866, 3897, 3908, 728],
 [3756, 3822, 3791, 0, 3865, 0]]
```

You might need to take care how you sort these keys, since they are strings, and lexicographic order might not be exactly what you want, but this should be enough to get you there.

*A little explanation for the one-liner: this uses a *set comprehension*, which is like a list comprehension but it populates a set instead, so it only keeps unique values. It is equivalent to:

```
temp_set = set()
for val in count.values(): # val will be a dict
    for v in val: # iterates over each key in val
        temp_set.add(v)
```

Sets, like `dict`s, are unordered, so I sort them:

```
possible = sorted(temp_set)
```

#### Edited to add

Suppose you want to sort some string keys to filter out only those that start with `i` and you want to sort by the *number* after the letter, then you could do:

```
In [27]: keys = ['i0','i1','i2','f2','s3','d3','i10','i11']

In [29]: sorted([k for k in keys if k.startswith('i')], key=lambda x: int(x[1:]))
Out[29]: ['i0', 'i1', 'i2', 'i10', 'i11']
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't use range function here. since my data will not be increment my 5000 always and I also need to figure out start/end for range.

Comment: @Romeo ok, then you'll have to do a couple of passes on the data to do some housekeeping. I've updated the solution.

Comment: Cool solution! Can you explain me what is this line doing: sorted({v for val in count.values() for v in val})

Comment: also how do I filter for only i0, i1, i2..i99 etc. unit. I have t0, t1, s11, s32 and other units also.

Comment: @Romeo added explanation and a quick solution to your key problem... assuming the keys you want (and only those keys) start with `"i"` it should be pretty simply. Also, you have to pass a key-function to `sorted` since lexicographic ordering isn't what you want.